# Why is my route not matching any action

Tags: regex, playframework

Using play framework, I'm trying to match a route using a regular expression.

What I wanted is to use one action that maps all this urls:

> mydomain.com/my-post-title-123
>
> mydomain.com/another-post-title-124
>
> mydomain.com/a-third-post-title-125

get this "123, 124 and 125" from the end of the url so the controller can use it. Basically ignore whatever post tile comes in and only use the number at the end.

I have the following on my routes.conf

```
GET         /$postId<\d$>         controllers.Posts.viewPost(postId: Int)
```

But I get the error page "Action not found"

Comment: If you want to get the last digits in the url, simply use `\d+$`... Anyway, the regex in your code is not the same as the one on regex101 !! (missing `$`)

Comment: thanks, I tried the expression you suggested and it is much simpler and it also matches what I need ... but still no luck with play matching to an action

Comment: You're missing the `+` in `\d+$` !!! If still no luck, then wait for someone else who knows that framework to pass by xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the url prefix and "+" in the regex in the routes definition. Here is my route configuration and it works fine

```
#Regex test
GET         /$prefix<.*>$postId<\d+$>         controllers.Application.viewPost(prefix:String,postId: Int)
```

## Controllers.Application.viewPost

```
def viewPost(prefix:String,postId:Int) = Action{
    Ok("the post id is: "+postId+" the prefix is:"+prefix)
  }
```

and the output will be

```
the post id is: 123 the prefix is "whatever/prefix/you/give"
```

** tested, it works.

Comment: thanks but I'm using a regular expression so I don't need to write one action for each post. I can't really add the url prefix as you suggest

Comment: I suppose you meant you dont want to write one action for each prefix. Check the updated answer, use 2 regular expressions, one to capture the prefix and one to capture the id. The point is capture everything in the path in your regex, not just the id and if you dont want the prefix, ignore it later

Comment: thanks, this one worked in the end `$prefix<.*->$postId<\d+$>`